# Include a range of cells for If/Then statement

Tags: excel

I have an IF statement that I want to have my 'true value' be true if (one of a range of cells values exist

```
=IF('Table Values'!C4='Table Values'!B84, 'Table Values'!C3, "<N/A>")
```

I want B84 to be B81 through B84

I tried

```
=IF('Table Values'!C4='Table Values'!B81:B84, 'Table Values'!C3, "<N/A>")
```

but that just shows #Value error in the cell

FYI - If this answer already exists tell me what my search criteria should have been to find my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have *happiness* in cell **A1** and we want to know if this can be found anywhere in column **B**.  Use this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),"Its there","no happiness")
```

[image]

Comment: This gave me the closest solution                 =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH('Table Values'!C4,'Table Values'!B84:B86)),"'Table Values'!C3"," ")

Comment: Still trying to determine how to make the 'array' using multiple cells

Comment: @DoowopDJ  How can we help??

Comment: The problem is worse.  I have 'ranges' of cells I want to include multiple options as being a true value.  Want to post an excel file to show the problem, not sure how to do that in this forum. I will re-edit my initial post to update my problem, as I am not sure of the mechanics/rules of this forum to update 'answered' questions

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing your question if in range B1:B4 there is the value in C4 you want to output C3. Please correct me if this is wrong. Based on this context, please consider the following formula:

```
{=IF(OR(C4=B81:B84),C3,"")}
```

Notice that the curly brackets represent that this formula is an array formula done by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER when inputting the formula. If you don't input it as an array formula it will only compare C84 with the top left most cell of the B81:B84 range (ie B81).

I can think of numerous other approaches to this, for example using a `COUNTIF` but I strived to follow your approach. Hope you find this useful. Cheers.

Comment: {=IF(OR(C4=B81:B84),C3,"")}  - I could not figure how to enter this into the formula field

Comment: You would type your formula as normal: `=IF(OR(C4=B81:B84),C3,"")` and then instead of just pressing `ENTER` to enable the formula you press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` to make it into an array formula and it would add the curly brackets at the ends. Here is a page explaining array formulas: http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html

Comment: First I need to reopen the question to revise the question? Is that the right way to handle the problem? Second i want to post a spreadsheet example  to show the problem i am trying to fix.  I think the Match:Index option may work, but i have not figured out the problem

Answer (score 0):

This gave me the closest solution, but now I have a problem expanding with the 'range' for other similar situations

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH('Table Values'!C4,'Table Values'!B84:B86)),"'Table Values'!C3"," ")

** Note: what is confusing to me about this is the 'isnumber', I am using 'text' not numbers, so that is why i did not consider it when i searched initially

And I now need to know how to use this for ranges with gaps

Example: instead of range B84:B86 I want my range to be B84:B86 and one other range C84:89.